# ADF Unpivot Dynamically With New Column

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-mapping-data-flow

There is an Excel worksheet that I wanted to unpivot all the columns after "Currency Code" into rows, the number of columns need to be unpivot might vary, new columns might be added after "NetIUSD". Is there a way to dynamically unpivot this worksheet with unknown columns?

[image]

It worked when I projected all the fields and define the datatype for all the numerical fields as "double" and set the unpivot column data type as "double" as well. However, the issue is there might be additional columns added to the source file, which I won't be able to define the datatype ahead, in this case, if the new column has different data type other than "double", it will throw an error that the new column is not of the same unpivot datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to repro this in Dataflow with sample input details.

[image]

- Take the unpivot transformation and in unpivot settings do the following.

```
Ungroup by:  Code, Currency_code
Unpivot column: Currency
Unpivoted Columns: Column arrangement: Normal
                   Column name: Amount
                   Type: string
```

[image: gif1112]

**Data Preview**

[image]

All columns other than mentioned in ungroup by can be dynamically unpivoted even if you add additional fields.

Comment: Hi Aswin, thanks for looking into this. I just wondering if you have projected the schema and datatype in the Source and set the datatype for the numerical fields as string as well?

Comment: I did not import projection and set the datatype manually.  Do you face any problems?

Comment: yes, I have imported projection and set the data type for the columns after "Currency Code" as "double" and also set the unpivot column "Amount" datatype as "double". So it throws an error when there is a new column added that it is not of the same unpivot datatype.

Comment: What is your source?

Comment: The columns that I wanted to unpivot they are "Custom" data type in Excel, if that's what you asked?

Comment: Okay. Change the datatype to string.

Comment: Thanks Aswin, it works when I set the type to string!

Answer (score 0):

I confirm an Aswin answer. Got the same issue: failed dataflow with dynamically new columns. The reason was in datatype of unpivoted columns. Changed that to string and all goes smoothly.
Imported projection does not affect this case i`ve tried both with imported and manually coded, both works with "string" datatype.

Comment: Yes, it worked after I changed all datatype to string. Thanks!